# Mongo Error :can't update node: 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I have configured project on Mongodb and Morphia.
When i try to fetch bulk data from Mongodb i get the following eerror on console saying ;

```
SEVERE: can't update node: 127.0.0.1:27017
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.mongodb.OutMessage.reset(OutMessage.java:73)
        at com.mongodb.OutMessage.<init>(OutMessage.java:51)
        at com.mongodb.OutMessage.query(OutMessage.java:38)
        at com.mongodb.DBPort.findOne(DBPort.java:127)
        at com.mongodb.DBPort.runCommand(DBPort.java:138)
        at com.mongodb.ReplicaSetStatus$Node.update(ReplicaSetStatus.java:149)
        at com.mongodb.ReplicaSetStatus.updateAll(ReplicaSetStatus.java:314)
        at com.mongodb.ReplicaSetStatus.ensureMaster(ReplicaSetStatus.java:306)
        at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.checkMaster(DBTCPConnector.java:396)
        at com.mongodb.ReplicaSetStatus$Updater.run(ReplicaSetStatus.java:275)
Apr 1, 2013 7:27:40 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
```

And this error runs continuously at the backend without hamaphering my flow of an application.How can i stop this error thead.
Your hep would be appreciable and Thnks in Advance :)

Comment: What version of the Java driver are you using?

Comment: Hi jyemin thnks for promt reply I am using JDK1.6

Comment: This is the code in configure.xml


        <property name="databaseURL" value="127.0.0.1"/>
        <property name="databasePort" value="27017"/>
        <property name="dbUsername" value=""/>
        <property name="dbPassword" value=""/>

I tried adding type"java.lang.String" but it gace comppilation error saying type cannot be a paramater for a prpoperty.

Answer (score 0):

can you provide detailed info(OS, Java, Driver, Morphia versions) and, if possible, java project dump?

Anyway, here there is a reference to similar issue, but was closed as not reproducible: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-357

Regards,
Moacy